# Select 1 Distinct Record per month by latest date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a list of data that looks like this:

```
 Name        Date           Weight 
Person 1    01/01/2014       89KG
Person 2    01/01/2014       62KG
Person 1    07/01/2014       88KG
Person 2    07/01/2014       62KG
Person 1    21/01/2014       85KG
Person 2    21/01/2014       63KG
```

What I would like to do is select only the records with a distinct name and are the latest dates in a given month. So for this example I would like to only select the person 1 and person 2 records for 21/01/2014 (as this is the latest date). I'm using SQL 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see if this works for you.

**Sample Data:**

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#TEMP') > 0
    BEGIN
       DROP TABLE #TEMP
    END

CREATE TABLE #TEMP(Name VARCHAR(20),
                WDate VARCHAR(20),
                Weight VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO #TEMP
VALUES
('Person 1', '01/01/2014', '89KG'),
('Person 2', '01/01/2014', '62KG'),
('Person 1', '07/01/2014', '88KG'),
('Person 1', '07/01/2014', '88KG'),
('Person 2', '07/02/2014', '62KG'),
('Person 1', '21/01/2014', '85KG'),
('Person 2', '21/01/2014', '63KG');
```

**Script:**

```
;WITH cte_DateFormat
    AS (
    SELECT Name,
         CONVERT(DATE, WDate, 103) AS WDate,
         Weight
    FROM #TEMP
    )
, cte_Rank
    AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name,
                                   CAST(YEAR(WDate) AS VARCHAR(4)) + CAST(MONTH(WDate) AS VARCHAR(2)) ORDER BY WDate DESC) AS ID,
         Name,
         WDate,
         Weight
    FROM cte_DateFormat
    )
    SELECT Name,
         WDate,
         Weight
    FROM cte_Rank
    WHERE ID = 1
```

**Cleanup Script:**

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#TEMP') > 0
    BEGIN
       DROP TABLE #TEMP
    END
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try using `DENSE_RANK`:

```
select 
  * 
From (
    select 
        *, 
        DENSE_RANK() over(PARTITION BY YEAR([Date]), 
                                     MONTH([Date]) 
                         ORDER BY [Date] desc) Rnk
    From tbl
)x where Rnk=1
```

Comment: That returns only the  latest values. I need to return the latest values per month. So for example over a year I would expect to return the latest value per person for Jan, Feb, March, April...etc  So the expected output would be 12 records per person if my dataset is over 1 year.

Comment: So you need to add a partition by in the dense_rank, check the edited answer.!

Comment: Should partition by year as well?

Comment: Thanks! However how could we edit this query to select the latest date per record - Each record could have a different latest date. Person 1's latest date could be 24/01 Person 2's latest date could be 26/07. The current query will only return Person 2's record as that would have rank 1.

Comment: @LiamF.O'Neill For that, you need to add `Name` as well in the `PARTITION BY` clause.

Answer (score 1):

This will also work, using row partitioning:

```
SELECT Name, Date, Weight
FROM (  SELECT
            Name, 
            Date, 
            Weight, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Name, MONTH(Date) 
                                ORDER BY Date DESC) AS [RowNum]
        FROM [YourTableHere]
        ) Tbl
WHERE Tbl.RowNum = 1
ORDER BY MONTH(Date), Name
```

Test Script:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (Name VARCHAR(20), Date Date, Weight VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @Table (Name, Date, Weight)
VALUES  ('Person 1', '1/1/2014', '89KG'),
        ('Person 2', '1/1/2014', '62KG'),
        ('Person 1', '1/7/2014', '88KG'),
        ('Person 2', '1/7/2014', '62KG'),
        ('Person 1', '1/21/2014', '85KG'),
        ('Person 2', '1/21/2014', '63KG'),
        ('Person 1', '2/1/2014', '84KG'),
        ('Person 2', '2/1/2014', '61KG'),
        ('Person 1', '2/11/2014', '83KG'),
        ('Person 2', '2/11/2014', '60KG')

SELECT Name, Date, Weight
FROM (  SELECT
            Name, 
            Date, 
            Weight, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Name, MONTH(Date) 
                                ORDER BY Date DESC) AS [RowNum]
        FROM @Table
        ) Tbl
WHERE Tbl.RowNum = 1
ORDER BY MONTH(Date), Name
```